# Skip navigation menu with links to different pages?

Tags: accessibility, wai-aria, wcag

We're currently updating our site for ADA compliance and want to implement a skip navigation menu on the main landing pages. The menu will offer skip nav links to "Login," "Main Content," and "Footer." The business offers three principle services, each of which has it's own landing page. The question I'm wrestling with is, is it useful or appropriate to offer two additional links in the skip navigation menu that redirect users to the two other business service landing pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would absolutely be an inappropriate use of skip links.

> "Skip links are internal page links which aid navigation around the current page, rather than to completely new pages. They are mainly used by screen reader users for bypassing or 'skipping' over repetitive web page content."
>
> https://www.nomensa.com/blog/2004/what-are-skip-links

The whole purpose of skip links is to help bypass navigation structures so that visitors don't have to listen to repetitive links on every page.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it useful or appropriate to offer two additional links in the skip navigation menu that redirect users to the two other business service landing pages?

Although it's not forbidden by any WCAG rule, mixing anchor links and internal links can be confusing for user experience. It would be quite hard to find a correct alternative name for the navigation menu.